# Something unknown reads data from my disks

Tags: server, 22.04

I've got a small server at home to access my files and the HDDs don't spin down. Currently it runs Ubuntu Server 22.04. Executing something like `$ cat /sys/block/sde/stat` displays some information including the total sectors read. If I wait for about 20 minutes and execute this command again, the total amount of sectors read increased.

```
$ cat /sys/block/sde/stat
 6886729 970027822 7822380784 1292509782    15759   276608  2297706   485868        0 30475568 1293440472        0        0        0        0    23680   444820
... Wait about 20 minutes
$ cat /sys/block/sde/stat
 6886734 970027822 7822380787 1292510398    15759   276608  2297706   485868        0 30476188 1293441088        0        0        0        0    23680   444820
```

But in theory there shouldn't be any process accessing this HDD.
This all started 2 days ago after upgrading to Ubuntu Server 22.04 from Ubuntu Server 20.04.

I already tried to use `<inside the correct directory>$ sudo fatrace -c`, but this didn't show anything. Also I tried to use `$ inotifywait -m -r /...`, still nothing.

How am I able to dig deeper so my HDDs are finally able to spin down again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

With `sudo dstat -tdD /dev/xxx --top-io` I was able to see which services did something with my drive. Those were in my case:

- smartd
- irqbalance
- udisks2

So I had to do

```
sudo systemctl stop udisks2.service # System still works, seems not to be so important
sudo systemctl disable udisks2.service
sudo systemctl stop smartd.service # SMART is nice, but not if the daemon prevents the drive from going into standby
sudo systemctl disable smartd.service
sudo systemctl stop irqbalance.service # If you got a server with hunders of drives this is meaningful for performance. In my case just overkill and prevents my drives from sleeping
sudo systemctl disable irqbalance.service
```

Thanks to [Artur Meinlid](https://askubuntu.com/users/1066942/artur-meinild) for the assistance.

---

Edit: At least I thought it was solved. I realized that `udisks2.service` restarts after some hours. The service is stopped and disabled but it still restarts. What the potatosalad?

---

Edit2: It was possible to mask this service.

```
sudo systemctl mask udisks2.service
sudo systemctl stop udisks2.service
```

Now this service doens't get restarted and the HDDs are sleeping. I tested this for a week now and everything works fine.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please consider upvoting (even though it's not the exact and full solution). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I'm unable to upvote anything. "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Answer (score 1):

##### Using `iotop`

You can monitor disk IO with `iotop`.

Install with:

```
sudo apt install iotop
```

And run:

```
iotop
```

This should tell you exactly which processes use disk and swap.

##### Using `htop`

You can also monitor IO directly with `htop` (although it's a sort of "hidden" feature).

Install with:

```
sudo apt install iotop
```

And run:

```
htop
```

Now press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to the IO screen (instead of the main screen). This gives info similar to `iotop`.

##### Using `udisksctl`

If you suspect the activity is related to `udisks`, you can try and run:

```
udisksctl monitor
```

This will tell you if there is activity with the `udisks` daemon.

Comment: I'm unable to filter for specific mount-points/HDDs in `iotop`.

Then I tried `dstat -tdD /dev/sde --top-io` and saw something like `04-07 14:06:30|1536B    0 |gvfs-udisks 465k  120B`

May this be the culprit?

Comment: Possibly related to the `gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service`: https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/500

Comment: `udisksctl monitor` really output something interesting: `14:36:27.466: /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/HGST_HDN724040AL_PK2334PEKD5RJT: org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive.Ata: Properties Changed
  SmartUpdated:         1688474187`

PS: I don't have microk8s installed, so there is no such service and no commands starting with `microk8s`

Comment: There is no such service like `gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service`. The closest I got is `run-user-1000-gvfs.mount`

Comment: Hmm ok. I think maybe the `udisksctl monitor` is a clue, but I don't know what it tells. `SmartUpdated` - sounds like SMART attributes maybe? But sorry, I really don't know.

Comment: May be related to  https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/issues/993 or https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/issues/892?

Comment: I think you're on to something.. 